# RemoteIpValve not doing it's job

Tags: ssl, tomcat

i have several Tomcat servers, behind a NetScaler load-balancer, which does SSL offloading. i've added the following line to server.xml on all of them:

```
     <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
            remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for" protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto" />
```

this works in all but 2 (identical) servers. i'm trying to get it to work on those two.

i've sniffed the traffic, and it contains the `x-forwarded-proto` header, with a value of `https`, as it should be. 
the returned result for `request.getHeader("x-forwarded-proto")` is `https`.
however, `request.getScheme()` returns `http` and `request.isSecure()` returns `false`.

how can i get the remoteIpValve working?

thanks.

Answer (score 7):

What's the remote IP of the load balancer?

The IP address of the connecting device (the load balancer, in this case) must be in the `internalProxies` configuration, otherwise the translations to the remote address, scheme, port, and request security are not applied.

By default, localhost and most of the RFC1918 ranges are allowed (except 172.16/12).  If your proxy's IP when connecting to the tomcat server is not in one of those ranges, you'll need to configure the `internalProxies` setting to allow your load balancer.

Comment: The clarification on the `172.16/12` IP range not being included in the regex was extremely helpful.  That tidbit is buried in the tomcat docs.